# Jquery: IE window width

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, width

my computer screen width is 1280 but why IE says it's 1259 but other browsers say 1280 with widht();?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($(window).width());
});
```

can it be fixed for IE?? have a look here,

http://ec-ener.eu/dump/index3.php

Thank,
Lau

Answer (score 3):

`window.width()` doesn't give you the screen's width, but the current window's.

IE will always show a disabled scroll bar to the right of your document, even when it's not needed.

I assume it's that width that gets subtracted in IE.

Try using [`screen.availWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.availWidth) to get the full screen width.

Comment: @lauthiamkok well, IE is basically doing it right.  Have you considered `screen.availWidth`?

Comment: yes now finally got it right with alert(window.screen.availWidth);

Comment: however, it stays at 1280 when you resize your browser window... never mind. thanks :-)

Comment: That's why you want `$(window).width()`. That returns the width of the viewport, which is what matters for your web page inside it. How big the *screen* is is almost never of any importance.

Comment: yes you are right - How big the screen is is almost never of any importance. I think I started the OP incorrectly, I should be looking for the width of the document which I still cannot solve it on IE but never I found other way to avoid using the width of the document. thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok IE is correct in showing the width of the document the way it does. It is taking into consideration the space the scroll bar is occupying.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).width()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you!

I found that using

```
var height = window.innerHeight || $(window).height();
var width = window.innerWidth || $(window).width();
```

will give the same value both in chrome and IE